# Matrix Multiplication and Normalization

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

$A$ is a $J \times K$ rectangular matrix.

$B$ is a $K \times L$ rectangular matrix.

$B$ is column-normalized: $\forall l: 1 = \sum_{k = 1}^{K}B_{kl}$

$AB$ is column-normalized: $\forall l: 1 = \sum_{j = 1}^{J}\sum_{k=1}^{K}A_{jk}B_{kl}$

Does this mean $A$ must also be column-normalized: $\forall k: 1 = \sum_{j = 1}^{J}A_{jk}$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a lot of algebra, it happened to be this way (unless I made a mistake). I want to know if this is true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally not true. Even for square matrices, it requires orthogonal matrices.
AB times B inverse is A.
Product of normalized matrices is a normalized matrix.